Understanding PyTorch Memory Management and GPU-to-CPU Transfers
Introduction:
I’m currently working on an application that uses PyTorch, and I’ve encountered an interesting behavior related to memory management. Specifically, when I load a model and move it from the CPU to the GPU, only part of the model is transferred to the GPU (which seems normal). However, when I move the model back from the GPU to the CPU, the entire model size is moved back, resulting in increased RAM usage. Even explicitly calling the garbage collector or using torch functions to free memory doesn’t seem to release the RAM (only GPU memory is freed).
Reproducing the Problem:
Below is the code snippet that demonstrates this issue:
import gc
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from memory_profiler import profile

INT_ITERATION = 5

class LargeNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LargeNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10000, 5000)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5000, 1000)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1000, 500)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(500, 100)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(100, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc4(x))
        x = self.fc5(x)
        return x


@profile
def run_test():
    # Create the network and move it to the GPU
    model = LargeNet()
    model = model.to('cuda')
    
    model = model.to('cpu')
    del model

    gc.collect()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("PyTorch version:", torch.__version__)

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        for i in range(INT_ITERATION):
            print(f'******* Iteration num: {i+1} *********** \n')
            run_test()

        input("Press Enter to continue...")
    
    else:
        print('CUDA is not available')
    

To run the code and reproduce the issue, you’ll need to have the torch and memory_profiler packages installed in your Python environment.
Output and Observations:
On my Ubuntu 20.04 machine with Torch 2.2.2 and CUDA 12.1 (I encountered the same issue on a Windows PC with Torch 2.1.0 and CUDA 12.1), I observed the following behavior:
******* Iteration num: 1 *********** 

Filename: test_torch_memory_leak.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    26    332.7 MiB    332.7 MiB           1   @profile
    27                                         def run_test():
    28                                             # Create the network and move it to the GPU
    29    546.9 MiB    214.1 MiB           1       model = LargeNet()
    30    451.2 MiB    -95.6 MiB           1       model = model.to('cuda')
    31                                         
    32    662.9 MiB    211.7 MiB           1       model = model.to('cpu')
    33    472.4 MiB   -190.5 MiB           1       del model
    34                                         
    35    472.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
    36    472.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       torch.cuda.empty_cache()


******* Iteration num: 2 *********** 

Filename: test_torch_memory_leak.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    26    472.4 MiB    472.4 MiB           1   @profile
    27                                         def run_test():
    28                                             # Create the network and move it to the GPU
    29    682.0 MiB    209.6 MiB           1       model = LargeNet()
    30    491.5 MiB   -190.5 MiB           1       model = model.to('cuda')
    31                                         
    32    682.0 MiB    190.5 MiB           1       model = model.to('cpu')
    33    491.5 MiB   -190.5 MiB           1       del model
    34                                         
    35    491.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
    36    491.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       torch.cuda.empty_cache()


******* Iteration num: 3 *********** 

Filename: test_torch_memory_leak.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    26    491.5 MiB    491.5 MiB           1   @profile
    27                                         def run_test():
    28                                             # Create the network and move it to the GPU
    29    701.1 MiB    209.6 MiB           1       model = LargeNet()
    30    510.6 MiB   -190.5 MiB           1       model = model.to('cuda')
    31                                         
    32    720.2 MiB    209.6 MiB           1       model = model.to('cpu')
    33    529.6 MiB   -190.5 MiB           1       del model
    34                                         
    35    529.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
    36    529.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       torch.cuda.empty_cache()


******* Iteration num: 4 *********** 

Filename: test_torch_memory_leak.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    26    529.6 MiB    529.6 MiB           1   @profile
    27                                         def run_test():
    28                                             # Create the network and move it to the GPU
    29    720.2 MiB    190.5 MiB           1       model = LargeNet()
    30    529.7 MiB   -190.5 MiB           1       model = model.to('cuda')
    31                                         
    32    682.4 MiB    152.7 MiB           1       model = model.to('cpu')
    33    491.6 MiB   -190.7 MiB           1       del model
    34                                         
    35    491.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
    36    491.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       torch.cuda.empty_cache()


******* Iteration num: 5 *********** 

Filename: test_torch_memory_leak.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    26    491.6 MiB    491.6 MiB           1   @profile
    27                                         def run_test():
    28                                             # Create the network and move it to the GPU
    29    701.2 MiB    209.6 MiB           1       model = LargeNet()
    30    510.6 MiB   -190.6 MiB           1       model = model.to('cuda')
    31                                         
    32    720.2 MiB    209.6 MiB           1       model = model.to('cpu')
    33    529.7 MiB   -190.5 MiB           1       del model
    34                                         
    35    529.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
    36    529.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       torch.cuda.empty_cache()


Press Enter to continue...

Interestingly, after 3 to 4 iterations, the memory usage stabilizes, and there is no further increase. However, this initial behavior is particularly annoying because the first time I load the model, I can use it with less memory compared to subsequent iterations.
Questions:

Is this behavior expected in PyTorch, or could it be an issue?
If this behavior is expected, is there a way to release all the Torch memory on the CPU without closing the thread?

